# Can confounders be controlled for in an Interrupted time series and when should outcomes be modeled as binary rather than aggregated rates?

Tags: regression, time-series, modeling, confounding

I just learned about interrupted time series and have a few questions about them.

Say I have a dataset of individual patients and I want to compare their monthly rates of getting a certain lab test before and after a policy change.

Questions:

1. Am I correct in thinking ITS can be used on both aggregated data AND individual level data directly? I found this paper ([Time After Time: Difference-in-Differences and Interrupted Time Series Models in SAS](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings20/4674-2020.pdf)) that makes it seem like it can be either, but other sources I read made it seems like it has to be aggregated?
2. With my example I am trying to look at rates of patients doing a lab test per month. In this case since the data can be individual, would I simply label each month of observation for each patient with a 1 if they had a test that month and a 0 if they did not?
3. How does one then control for covariates in this scenario, like say age or sex or weight etc? I never see any mention of controlling for covariates in tutorials like one would do in a linear or logistic regression?
4. One thing I’ve read is taking the covariates and looking at them before and after the interruption to see if they change, but what does that mean in this case, does it mean look at the covariates of the individual patients who contributed to the pre or post periods, or am I supposed to aggregate the covariates like I do with the outcome?
5. What if I wanted to see if the slopes varied based on subgroups (such as insurance type of the patient)? Would I simply rerun the model for each subgroup separately, or can I add an interaction term?

Comment: Would love to hear an answer to this, as I have the same problem using aggregates in an ITS.

Comment: I have the same issue also